# How can I nest a typeit-react component within another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a component called Header in which I would like to use a component called TypeIt from the typeit-react package. I'm getting the error "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." when I attempt to do this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TypeIt from 'typeit-react';

class Header extends Component {

  render() {

    if(this.props.data){
      var name = this.props.data.name;
      var occupation= this.props.data.occupation;
      var description= this.props.data.description;
      var city= this.props.data.address.city;
      var networks= this.props.data.social.map(function(network){
        return <li key={network.name}><a href={network.url} target="_blank"><i className={network.className}></i></a></li>
      })
    }

    return (
      <header id="home">

      <div className="row banner">
         <div className="banner-text">
            <h3>Hello, my name is</h3>
            <h1 className="responsive-headline">John Doe</h1>
            <h3><span id="type-it">I am a</span></h3>
            <div className="type-it">
            <TypeIt>This will be typed in a `span` element!</TypeIt>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <ul className="social">
               {networks}
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>

   </header>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

The error is produced by the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

and for additional context, this is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
import $ from 'jquery';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import About from './Components/About';
import Resume from './Components/Resume';
import Portfolio from './Components/Portfolio';
import TypeIt from 'typeit-react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: 'bar',
      resumeData: {}
    };

    ReactGA.initialize('UA-110570651-1');
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);

  }

  getResumeData(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'/resumeData.json',
      dataType:'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({resumeData: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err){
        console.log(err);
        alert(err);
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getResumeData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header data={this.state.resumeData.main}/>
        <About data={this.state.resumeData.main}/>
        <Resume data={this.state.resumeData.resume}/>
        <Portfolio data={this.state.resumeData.portfolio}/>
        <Footer data={this.state.resumeData.main}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem seems to be with nesting components (i.e. nesting TypeIt within Header), but I'm not sure about finding a way around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Error: Invalid hook call` means you are using a hook somewhere you are not suppose to. The problem is probably not in this component since there is no hook used in here.

Comment: The error appears to be generated because of this component, but it's produced by my index.js. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: `App.js` is pretty much your entire application so it doesn't really help narrow things down. You can try comment out each of the `Header`, `About`, `Resume`, etc... and see when the error went away to focus down on where the problematic code is.

Comment: When I comment out ```<div className="type-it"><TypeIt>This will be typed in a `span` element!</TypeIt></div>``` from Header.js, the error goes away, so that's the problematic code. I just want to know a way to use the TypeIt component within my Header component.

Comment: It almost sounds like `TypeIt` can't be used in a class component. Have you tried converting your `Header` into a functional component?

Comment: I still suspect the problem is elsewhere. Here is a Code Sandbox with your `Header` code that's working with no errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/type-it-forked-7uwfb?file=/src/Foo.js
It might help if you could produce a working example in Code Sandbox that demonstrate the error you are seeing.